# NSDate issue.. Incorrect time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDate not returning correct date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554999/nsdate-not-returning-correct-date)

when I try to display current time like so:
    NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];

I get this result:

```
2012-11-24 09:27:13.194 myApp[5284:c07] mydate = 2012-11-24 07:27:13 +0000
```

the time is off by two hours although the simulator time and OS X time is different. How can I fix that? Thank you in advance..

Comment: Check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3413414/1548523

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6741519/927947 & http://stackoverflow.com/q/6554999/927947

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out the date with an NSDateFormatter. NSDate doesn't have any timezone information attached to it. Make sure to attach a timezone to your date formatter.

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

// GET A DATE FORMATTER AND SET THE TIMEZONE
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

// CHANGE FORMAT TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS
[df setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterFullStyle]; 
[df setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

// GET YOUR FORMATTED DATE STRING
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate: now];
```